# Can't install openSDK 6 - ubuntu 10.04

Tags: software-installation, java

While trying to install openJDK to start installing **netbeans 6.9** - I'm getting this:

> The installation could have failed
>   because of an error in the
>   corresponding software package or it
>   was cancelled in an unfriendly way.
>   You have to repair this before you can
>   install or remove any further
>   software.

I read it... and I have no clue what to do next. :( 
**how can we repair that?**

I have forget openSDK and I'm trying the java one. All seems to go well... but know I'm stuck here:
[image: jdk on terminal]

And here is the amazing question:
**How can I click or hit, or push or something, that OK?**

Arrows, Page Up and Page Down work. 
Enter and Click don't.

Anyone?

K. Regards,
MEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

EDIT:

As the original message says, you have to repair the error (run the above command) regardless.  However, if you do want to install the Sun JRE, you use tab to get to the OK.

Comment: Thanks. How more newbie can we get? Stuck on a screen... still how can we guess the tab? :s

;) Thanks.

Comment: @Mathew - About the command, and if you don't mind to reply, how does ubuntu knows that we are talking about a specific thing that goes wrong, and it's that that should be repaired and not something else?

Thanks.

Comment: @MEM, the [package management system](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/package-management.html) (APT) keeps track of what packages still need to be configured.  So it knows that the OpenJDK configuration hasn't finished successfully yet.